# XSL range of number

Tags: xml, xslt, logical-operators

First, I have to admit I'm a newbie in XML, so forgive me stupid questions.

My goal is to get the value of `$majorGoal`.

```
<xsl:variable name="variable">
  <xsl:value-of select="(../@attribute) * 100 />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">25</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2">20</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal2">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">40</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2">24</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal3">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">55</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2 and &lt; 4">50</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= 4">50</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal4">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">80</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2 and &lt; 4">70</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= 4">60</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- I have 10 more similar variables  -->

<xsl:variable name="minorGoal">
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$anotherVariable = 30">
    <xsl:value-of select="$minorGoal1"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$anotherVariable = 40">
    <xsl:value-of select="$minorGoal2"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$anotherVariable = 50">
    <xsl:value-of select="$minorGoal3"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="$anotherVariable = 60">
    <xsl:value-of select="$minorGoal4"/>
  </xsl:when>

<!-- Another 10 more similar variables  -->

</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="majorGoal">
  <xsl:value-of select="$minorGoal"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

@attribute refers to the source xml file.
$anotherVariable is defined as a global variable, in the same xsl, file and is constant.

The problem is that the parser returns an error:

> Expression expected.
>   $variable >= -2 and --><<-- 4

I can guess the problem is caused by:

```
<xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2 and &lt; 4">50</xsl:when>
```

but how else describe a range of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by Mathias, to test if a variable is between -2 and 4, you need to do:

```
 test="$variable &gt;= -2 and $variable &lt; 4"
```

However, the idea with `choose` is that the first test that returns true terminates the process and returns the corresponding result. This means that instead of:

```
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal4">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">80</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2 and $variable &lt; 4">70</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= 4">60</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

you can write simply:

```
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal4">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">80</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; 4">70</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>60</xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

which is both easier to read and more efficient to perform.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to label XSLT questions as XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, since the answers are very often different.

In XSLT 2.0 you can say

```
test="$var = (25 to 40)"
```

although this places some demands on the optimizer, so

```
test="$var ge 25 and $var le 40"
```

might be safer.

Also in XSLT 2.0 you can simplify this

```
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal4">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &lt; -2">80</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= -2 and $variable &lt; 4">70</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$variable &gt;= 4">60</xsl:when>
  <xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

to this:

```
<xsl:variable name="minorGoal4" select="
    if ($variable lt -2) then 80
    else if ($variable lt 4) then 70
    else 60"/>
```

with the added bonus that the result is a number rather than a result tree fragment, which is likely to be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mention `$variable` in both parts of the AND. Also make sure that `$variable` is really a number and not a string or untyped atomic.

Besides, if you are using `XSLT 2.0`, the first expression can be shortened to `ge` which means "equal or greater than".

```
<xsl:when test="number($variable) ge -2 and number($variable) lt 4">
70
</xsl:when>
```

An example to illustrate this:

**XML input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <number>6</number>
   <number>3</number>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="number">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(.) ge -2 and number(.) lt 4">
               <xsl:text>YES</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text>NO</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <number>NO</number>
   <number>YES</number>
</root>
```

Comment: The OP didn't say whether this is XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - `ge` and `lt` are 2.0-only, whereas the `>=` and `<` operators used in the question will work in both versions.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll say this explicitly.